# Parse de Json em C#

Tags: c#, json, parse, newtonsoft

Estou a tentar fazer parse de Json para uma listbox e não estou a ter sucesso.

Este [url](https://api.tibiadata.com/v2/characters/Trollefar.json) é um exemplo do que eu estou a tentar fazer parse... e isto é o que eu tenho:

```
public void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    dynamic m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@"https://api.tibiadata.com/v2/characters/"+textBox1.Text+".json");
    string name = m.Name;
    listBox1.Items.Add(name);

}
```

E tenho este erro:

> Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: 'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: h. Path '', line 0, position 0.'

Comment: Este é o site do SO em português, traduza sua pergunta

Comment: O seu problema está no facto de não estar a passar nenhum ficheiro/string json ao DeserializeObject, está a passar apenas o url e não foi realizado nenhum pedido a esse endereço para obter a informação que será desserializada.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Um exemplo de uma estrutura em **C#** para usar a informação desse ficheiro em formato **Json**, realizei este exemplo usando este [site](http://json2csharp.com/)

```
public class Guild
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string rank { get; set; }
}

public class LastLogin
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public int timezone_type { get; set; }
    public string timezone { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string sex { get; set; }
    public string vocation { get; set; }
    public int level { get; set; }
    public int achievement_points { get; set; }
    public string world { get; set; }
    public string residence { get; set; }
    public string married_to { get; set; }
    public Guild guild { get; set; }
    public List<LastLogin> last_login { get; set; }
    public string comment { get; set; }
    public string account_status { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Achievement
{
    public int stars { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}

public class Created
{
    public string date { get; set; }
    public int timezone_type { get; set; }
    public string timezone { get; set; }
}

public class AccountInformation
{
    public string loyalty_title { get; set; }
    public Created created { get; set; }
}

public class OtherCharacter
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string world { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
}

public class Characters
{
    public Data data { get; set; }
    public List<Achievement> achievements { get; set; }
    public List<object> deaths { get; set; }
    public AccountInformation account_information { get; set; }
    public List<OtherCharacter> other_characters { get; set; }
}

public class Information
{
    public int api_version { get; set; }
    public double execution_time { get; set; }
    public string last_updated { get; set; }
    public string timestamp { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Characters characters { get; set; }
    public Information information { get; set; }
}
```

Para realizar a desserialização estou a usar [Json.NET](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
RootObject rObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

Comment: Obrigado, entendi muito bem!

Comment: @SérgioAbreu Ainda bem que entendeu, coloque então a minha resposta como a aceite.