# Problemas ao passar um objeto em uma requisição HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-request, postman

Estou criando uma API DotNet, e quando tentei testar uma requisição Post com o Postman os únicos dados que estão chegando ao método do meu controller são Nome e CPF.

Abaixo esta uma imagem com a requisição que estou fazendo no Postman

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Abaixo a classe do objeto que estou passando via Post.

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace PimVIIIAPI.Model
{
   public class Pessoa
   {
      [Key]
      protected int Id { get; set; }
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o nome")]
      public string Nome { get; set; }
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o cpf")]
      public long Cpf { get; set; }
      [Required(ErrorMessage = "Informe o endereço")]
      public Endereco Endereco = new Endereco();
      public Telefone[] Telefone = new Telefone []{new Telefone()};
   }
}
```

Não consigo entender o porque todos os dados não estão sendo recebidos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Acredito ter criado a requisição corretamente e passado o objeto da forma correta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente você não está conseguindo porque precisa desseralizar o contéudo que recebe através da requisição. O método da sua controller ficaria algo como:

```
InserirPessoa(dynamic args){
    Pessoa objPessoa;
    try
    {
        objPessoa =
            new Pessoa()
            {
                Nome = args.Nome,
                CPF = args.CPF,
                Endereco = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Endereco>(args.Endereco),
                Telefone = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Telefone>>(args.Telefone),
            };
    }
    catch
    {
        throw;
    }

    //salvar
}
```

Espero ter ajudado..

Comment: Entendi, realizarei este teste hoje mesmo, obrigado......

Comment: Não funcionou vou continuar tentando, no caso do objeto dinamico eu recebi os dados corretamente mas não consigo passa-los para meu objeto do tipo Pessoa da forma que me passou o exemplo.

Answer (score 0):

Depois de tentar bastante e com base na dica apresentada consegui resolver o problema com um outra [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/394990/parse-de-json-em-c/394992#394992) que acabei esbarrando aqui mesmo no stackoverflow.

E acabei implementando a seguinte solução no meu controller.

```
[HttpPost("InsertPessoa/{pessoa}")]
    public bool InsertPessoa(object pessoa)
    {

        dynamic m = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(pessoa.ToString());
        Pessoa p = new Pessoa();

        try
        {
            p.Nome = m.Nome;
            p.Cpf = m.Cpf;
            p.Endereco.Logradouro = m.Endereco.Logradouro;
            p.Endereco.Numero = m.Endereco.Numero;
            p.Endereco.Cep = m.Endereco.Cep;
            p.Endereco.Bairro = m.Endereco.Bairro;
            p.Endereco.Cidade = m.Endereco.Cidade;
            p.Endereco.Estado = m.Endereco.Estado;

            p.Telefone[0].Ddd = m.Telefone[0].Ddd;
            p.Telefone[0].Numero = m.Telefone[0].Numero;
            p.Telefone[0].Tipo.Tipo = m.Telefone[0].Tipo.Tipo;


        }
        catch(Exception er)
        {
            throw new Exception(er.Message);
        }
        return PessoaDAO.Insira(p);
    }
```

Desta forma consegui receber corretamente os dados do Json.

Meu muito obrigado ao

> [Juliano Roberto](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/213726/juliano-roberto)

Por tirar um tempo e me dar essa força da resposta aqui, que me ajudou a achar exatamente o que eu precisava.